# Shell Scripting output ISO8601

Tags: shell, openwrt, iso8601

Newbie question! :)
I'm trying to save on an output file ( .csv ) the time formatted as ISO8601.
I wrote a script that is running on an embedded board with OpenWRT.

```
NEW_DATA=$(date --iso-8601=seconds) 
printf "${NEW_DATA};"
```

On an online Bash compiler works great, but not on my board time is not printed out.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: Nothing is printed ? For me locally it works well.

Comment: Hi Archit Goyal, thank you for your reply.
It works on an online bash compiler, but not on my embedded board.
How did you test it?

Thanks

Comment: it seems that the "=seconds" is the problem..don't know how to solve.
Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Try using `date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z `

Comment: Try ` date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" ` and lemme know if it works then I can make it as an answer

Comment: Or `date -Iseconds` (BusyBox v1.28.3, default OpenWrt config).

Comment: @ koniu thank you for your reply.
Where did you find this?

Comment: Update: I tried with "DATA_ISO8601=$(date -Iseconds)"  this is the output:

2018-07-25T11:23:00+0200
is the +0200 without ':' ISO8601 compliant? I see on Wikipedia that should be 2018-07-25T11:23:00+02:00

Thanks

Comment: ISO8601 distinguish between basic and extended format. Only the later one using hyphen and colon as separators for a better readability. Bot many other standards are requiring more string subsets, e.g. ECMAScript. So be clear if compliance to ISO 8601 is enough or if you have to support a a specific subset.